# WordPress automatic publish: is there a timeout when WordPress won't publish anymore?

Tags: wp-cron, cron, scheduled-posts

When you schedule a post for publish, and it misses its publish time, for how long after that will WordPress publish it?

I know that WordPress cron jobs trigger when a user loads the page after the cron job is set to run, but how long after the scheduling time will WordPress still publish the post?

E.g: If the publish time is set to 12:00 pm, and the first user after 12:00 visits 12:30 pm, will WordPress still publish? What is the limit here?

I will admit that I didn't google that much before asking, but I saw mostly tutorials on how to set up the publishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit.  Once the next person visits the site the cron queue runs regardless of how much of a gap there has been.

The only caveat is that if you have a job that you've scheduled to run hourly and 2hrs pass between vists to the site, the job will only run once when the next person comes.

Comment: So a post will only be marked as 'missed schedule' only if the cron jobs is disabled and the set time passes? (can probably be more reasons though)

Comment: "Missed Schedule" usually happens if the wp-cron ran but for some reason did not get to publishing the post or if wp-cron hasn't run for some reason (including being disabled entirely).